# How to conditionally concat 2 columns in Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': [1, "Avoid", 3, "Avoid"], 'col2': ["AA", "BB", "Avoid", "Avoid"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    col1    col2
0   1       AA
1   Avoid   BB
2   3       Avoid
3   Avoid   Avoid
```

I have to conditionally concat **col1** and **col2** into **col3**. Conditions:

- Only concat 2 columns as long as none of them is **Avoid**.
- If any of **col1** and **col2** is Avoid, **col3** will be equal to **Avoid** as well.
- When performing concatination, **" & "** needs to be added between column values in **col3**. For instance, first row of **col3** will be **"1 & AA"**.

The end result is supposed to look as the following:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   1       AA      1 & AA
1   Avoid   BB      Avoid
2   3       Avoid   Avoid
3   Avoid   Avoid   Avoid
```

How can I do this without dealing with for loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df["col3"]=df.apply(lambda x:"Avoid" if x["col1"]=="Avoid" or x["col2"]=="Avoid" else f"{x['col1']} & {x['col2']}",axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Is not an efficient way to work with pandas, but if you can't change the data structure these are solutions:

Solution 1:

```
def custom_merge(cols):
    if cols["col1"]=="Avoid" or cols["col2"]=="Avoid":
        return "Avoid"
    else:
        return f"{cols['col1']} & {cols['col2']}"
    
df['col3'] = df.apply(custom_merge, axis=1)
```

Solution 2:

```
df['col3'] = (df["col1"].astype(str) + " & " + df["col2"].astype(str)).apply(lambda x: "Avoid" if 'Avoid' in x else x)
```

Both solutions results in the following:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   1       AA      1 & AA
1   Avoid   BB      Avoid
2   3       Avoid   Avoid
3   Avoid   Avoid   Avoid
```

**Execution Time comparison**

In this section I will count the execution times of the proposed solutions.
@mozway proposed 2 very tricky solutions in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73716109/9302488), which I will call Solution 3a and Solution 3b. Another interesting solution is [@sammywemmy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73717274/9302488) that uses a list comprehension and then adds the list to the dataframe, I will call this solution solution 4

The instances of the experiments will have the following structure:

```
import pandas as pd
n = 100000
d = {'col1': [1, "Avoid", 3, "Avoid"] * n, 'col2': ["AA", "BB", "Avoid", "Avoid"] * n}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Execution time:

- Solution 1:

  ```
  %timeit 3.56 s ± 71.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
  ```
- Solution 2:

  ```
  %timeit 140 ms ± 1.53 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
  ```
- Solution 3a:

  ```
  %timeit 3.44 s ± 77.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
  ```
- Solution 3b:

  ```
  %timeit 893 ms ± 13.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
  ```
- Solution 4:

  ```
  %timeit 191 ms ± 5.71 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
  ```

Solution 1 and solution 3a have similar execution times on the instance under consideration. Solution 3b runs 4 times faster than solutions 1 and 3a. The fastest solution is solution 2 which goes about 7 times faster than solution 2 and about 25 times faster than solutions 1 and 3a. This is because solution 2 takes advantage of [pandas vectorization](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/pandas-vectorization/). Solution 4 has a similar runtime as solution 2, taking advantage of list comprehension for the merge operation (without using pandas).

**TIPS**:
If you can change the data format, the advice is to format the data so that you can use the native pandas functions to do the [join operations](https://realpython.com/pandas-merge-join-and-concat/) or if you can't change the data format and can do without pandas you might have a slight speed up over solution 2 using dictionaries or lists, doing the merge operation using list comphrehnsion.

Answer (score 3):

Run a list comprehension on the strings in plain python:

```py
out = [f"{l}&{r}" 
        if 'Avoid' not in {l, r} 
        else 'Avoid' 
        for l, r in zip(df.col1, df.col2)]
df.assign(col3 = out)
    col1   col2   col3
0      1     AA   1&AA
1  Avoid     BB  Avoid
2      3  Avoid  Avoid
3  Avoid  Avoid  Avoid
```

Answer (score 1):

Use boolean operations, this enables you to use an arbitrary number of columns:

```
# is any value in the row "Avoid"?
m = df.eq('Avoid').any(1)

# concatenate all columns unless there was a "Avoid"
df['col3'] = df.astype(str).agg(' & '.join, axis=1).mask(m, 'Avoid')
```

Alternative that should be faster if you have many rows and few with "Avoid":

```
m = df.ne('Avoid').all(1)

df.loc[m, 'col3'] = df[m].astype(str).agg(' & '.join, axis=1)

df['col3'] = df['col3'].fillna('Avoid')
```

output:

```
    col1   col2    col3
0      1     AA  1 & AA
1  Avoid     BB   Avoid
2      3  Avoid   Avoid
3  Avoid  Avoid   Avoid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df["col3"] = df["col1"] + " & " + df["col2"]
df["col3"] = df["col3"].apply(lambda x: "Avoid" if x.contains("Avoid") else x)
```